# How to find which grid cell my point is in using R?

Tags: r

Similar questions have been asked before, but they are either for some complicated raster mapping or are for Python. I am trying to find the minimum values of a grid cell which a given point is in. For example, if I have a grid that looks like the one below:

[image: grid]

My point is in grid cell -7.3, 55.3. That is, these are the minimal values needed to tell me which grid cell my point is in.

So, if I have some data that looks like this:

```
lo <-  -c(7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8.0)
la <- c(55, 55.1, 55.2, 55.3, 55.4, 55.5)

df <- data.frame(long =  c(lo, lo, lo, lo, lo, lo),
                 lat = c(rep(55,11), rep(55.1,11), rep(55.2,11), rep(55.3,11), rep(55.4,11), rep(55.5,11))
                 )

myPoint = c(-7.24, 55.36)
```

Here, `df` defines my grid and `myPoint` is the point that im trying to find the grid reference of.

I was trying something like this to solve it:

```
df[which.min(abs(myPoint[1]-df$long)),][1]
df[which.min(abs(myPoint[2]-df$lat )),][2]
```

but this gives me the closest grid values. Im looking for the minimum grid values.

Any suggestion as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```r
df[which(floor(myPoint[1] * 10) == df$long * 10 & 
         floor(myPoint[2] * 10) == df$lat  * 10), ]
#>    long  lat
#> 37 -7.3 55.3
```